# Iterate over pandas group by giving typeerror

Tags: python, pandas

I am grouping pandas df and wish to see each of those group but getting error.

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'c1':10, 'c2':True, 'c3': False}, {'c1':10, 'c2':True, 'c3': True}, {'c1':11, 'c2':True, 'c3': True}, {'c1':13, 'c2':True, 'c3': True}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

temp = df.groupby('c1')

for i, df_i in tqdm(temp):
    print(df_i)


TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you are probably doing `import tqdm` instead of `from tqdm import tqdm`, its a common mistake, you can avoid it just changing the `import`.